# Pinterest API App in dev mode (so I can use http redirect)

Tags: javascript, oauth, pinterest

When doing dev against pinterest API, I'm running a simple dev server, without https. The pinterest API appears to only allow https URIs, no matter how I try to work around it.

Is there a way to put the app in specifically-dev mode, and allow a non-encrypted redirect URI?

I was kinda directed here by their support page, so if this is not the place to ask company-specific api questions, please let me know, and I'll remove it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't a way.  I ran into the same problem and had to install an SSL certificate in order to obtain the token and post messages.

Comment: Yeah, I got a response from their support saying the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), It allows you to use https in your dev env (localhost)

After downloading extract the file, then simply run from terminal ./ngrock http 80,

It will give you a https url which will point to localhost. There's a lot of configuration that can be done.

By this you can use the https url as pinterest callback. I'm using that for dev also.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I wound up using something similar, a ruby program called tunnels. It's working pretty well.